# QWidget created with QtDesigner is not visible when added to QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I have created a QWidget with a bunch of QToolButtons in it and I managed to successfully initialize it and show it as a separate window using

```
myWidget.setVisible(true)
```

My ultimate goal is however to add this widget to a QToolBar to show on *Qt::LeftToolBarArea* of my QMainWindow. I add *myWidget* to QToolBar using

```
myToolBar.addWidget(myWidget)
```

The QToolBar is successfully added to my QMainWindow (I can see the handle used to move it around the different toolbar areas of my QMainWindow and can move it around). However my QWidget is not visible. I tried

```
myToolBar.addWidget(myWidget).setVisible(true)
```

as specified by the manuals since *setVisible()* won't work unless called on a QAction. I tried to add other pre-made widgets such as a QPushButton to my QToolBar and that is being visualized successfully.

Is there anything special that I need to do to my widget to make it visible in a QToolBar?

Regards,

C

<< EDIT >>

So, as I said, I created myWidget using qtDesigner so I can show you what that created and hopefully is not too long:

*OnlineAssemblerPlayer.ui*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>OnlineAssemblerPlayer</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="OnlineAssemblerPlayer">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>211</width>
    <height>30</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="horizontalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>211</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>...</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>...</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

*OnlineAssemblerPlayer.h*

```
#ifndef ONLINEASSEMBLERPLAYER_H
#define ONLINEASSEMBLERPLAYER_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class OnlineAssemblerPlayer;
}

class OnlineAssemblerPlayer : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit OnlineAssemblerPlayer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~OnlineAssemblerPlayer();

private:
    Ui::OnlineAssemblerPlayer *ui;
};

#endif // ONLINEASSEMBLERPLAYER_H
```

*OnlineAssemblerPlayer.cc*

```
#include "OnlineAssemblerPlayer.h"
#include "ui_OnlineAssemblerPlayer.h"

OnlineAssemblerPlayer::OnlineAssemblerPlayer(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OnlineAssemblerPlayer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

OnlineAssemblerPlayer::~OnlineAssemblerPlayer()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And the *ui_OnlineAssemblerPlayer.h* generated by Qt

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'OnlineAssemblerPlayer.ui'
**
** Created: Wed Jul 4 16:23:39 2012
**      by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.8.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_ONLINEASSEMBLERPLAYER_H
#define UI_ONLINEASSEMBLERPLAYER_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QComboBox>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QToolButton>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_OnlineAssemblerPlayer
{
public:
    QWidget *horizontalLayoutWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QToolButton *toolButton_2;
    QToolButton *toolButton;
    QComboBox *comboBox;

    void setupUi(QWidget *OnlineAssemblerPlayer)
    {
        if (OnlineAssemblerPlayer->objectName().isEmpty())
            OnlineAssemblerPlayer->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("OnlineAssemblerPlayer"));
        OnlineAssemblerPlayer->resize(211, 30);
        horizontalLayoutWidget = new QWidget(OnlineAssemblerPlayer);
        horizontalLayoutWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"));
        horizontalLayoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 211, 31));
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(horizontalLayoutWidget);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"));
        horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        toolButton_2 = new QToolButton(horizontalLayoutWidget);
        toolButton_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("toolButton_2"));

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(toolButton_2);

        toolButton = new QToolButton(horizontalLayoutWidget);
        toolButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("toolButton"));

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(toolButton);

        comboBox = new QComboBox(horizontalLayoutWidget);
        comboBox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("comboBox"));

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(comboBox);


        retranslateUi(OnlineAssemblerPlayer);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(OnlineAssemblerPlayer);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *OnlineAssemblerPlayer)
    {
        OnlineAssemblerPlayer->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("OnlineAssemblerPlayer", "Form", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        toolButton_2->setText(QApplication::translate("OnlineAssemblerPlayer", "...", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        toolButton->setText(QApplication::translate("OnlineAssemblerPlayer", "...", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class OnlineAssemblerPlayer: public Ui_OnlineAssemblerPlayer {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_ONLINEASSEMBLERPLAYER_H
```

Then I initialize it in the constructor of my QMainWindow like this:

```
OnlineAssemblerPlayer *mOnlineAssemblerPlayer = new OnlineAssemblerPlayer;

QToolBar *mToolbarAssemblerPlayer = new QToolBar(tr("AssemblerPlayer"));

mToolbarAssemblerPlayer->addWidget(mOnlineAssemblerPlayer);
mToolbarAssemblerPlayer->setMovable(true);
mToolbarAssemblerPlayer->setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllToolBarAreas);
addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, mToolbarAssemblerPlayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set visible of your toolbar. Are you sure that you add anything to your widget look? I'm almost sure that you didn't set any widget look. Can you show us code of 'myWidget' and something more from adding widget to toolbar?

EDIT

Try to add

```
setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);
```

right after

```
retranslateUi(OnlineAssemblerPlayer);
```

Comment: I cannot do that as setLayout() is not defined for _Ui_OnlineAssemblerPlayer_ but you were right. That was the problem. Solved by calling setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout) in the constructor of _OnlineAssemblerPlayer_. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Oh, you are right. Corrected that. No problem, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into similar problem: created a custom widget (`QWidget` subclass with a member `QListView`) and tried to add it to a `QToolBar` of my `QMainWindow`. It didn't show up no matter what I did despite being reparented to the `QToolBar` successfully. Though simple default widgets (button, textedits and even listview) were visible and working nicely.

I didn't make it work in the end, but figured out that `QToolBar` actually operates not with `QWidgets` but with `QActions`: even adding widget through addWidget(wgt*) it only adds some QAction connected with wgt.

Now it seems logical that adding custom widget consisting of some default widgets like QButton, the QToolBar just doesn't know how to display it. As I understand it's solved with **`QWidgetAction`** that is implemented in order to add custom widget functionality to a `QToolBar`, `QMenu` etc - all that uses `QActions`. `QWidgetAction`'s virtual functions `createWidget(QWidget*)` and `deleteWidget(QWidget*)` serve that goal.

But in my case I avoided the problem: inherited not from `QWidget`, adding `QListView` in it, but directly from `QListView`. This way I could freely add it to the toolbar with its `addWidget()`.